# Keyboard does not work after reboot

Tags: boot, keyboard

I was running an Ubuntu 12.04, which I later upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 in the hopes of fixing my problem, which is as follows:

When I turn on the Notebook, a Toshiba of the Satellite series, sometimes (not always, no specific pattern to be found) the keyboard will not work at all. Not the keystrokes and not the NUM/CAPS-Lock keys. It just wont accept any input at all. Also there is no use in pressing a key really long in order to fix the problem. The problem is that I am an absolute Ubuntu beginner, so I don't even know where to start to fix it. Is there any way to reinstall the drivers or something similar? Anyone with the same problem.

Thank you very much,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

well, I've met this bug - and usually I do one of the following
 - I wait ~3 minutes, then keyboard becomes active, but is important to not touch any key

or

- activate screen keyboard, top right corner - accesibility and write your password, then press enter - all using screen keyboard + mouse and after login keyboard will work :)

some of my friends also told me that keyboard is not working if a usb camera is connected to pc